# Shell script comparing strings

Tags: shell

Here's part of a shellscript I'm writing checking passwords stored in a file (along with names):

```
VALID_PASSWORD=`grep "Karl Marks" hiddenpasswords.txt|cut -f2 -d,`
echo $VALID_PASSWORD
echo enter password1
echo "Please enter the password"
read PASSWORD
if test "$PASSWORD" = "$VALID_PASSWORD"
then
echo "you have access"
else
echo "access denied"
fi
```

The grep part takes the correct password from the file, however "access denied"  is always run no matter what I type in.

Comment: Chances are that there is a space after `VALID_PASSWORD`.  Try saying `echo "${VALID_PASSWORD}."`

Comment: What happens when you run the script with `sh -x`?  Does that tell you what is going wrong?  Have you tried echoing `echo "[$VALID_PASSWORD]"` with the square brackets to indicate the limits of the variable? Have you tried `echo "[$PASSWORD]"` to see what that yields?

Comment: If you don't want the entered password to be visible as the user types it, use `read -s PASSWORD` (assuming you use bash)

Answer (score 1):

> `The grep part takes the correct password from the file, however "access denied" is always run no matter what I type in.`

It could be due to presence of whitespaces in your `$VALID_PASSWORD`.

Try changing first line to:

```
VALID_PASSWORD=$(awk -F '[, ]+' '/Karl Marks/ {print $2}' hiddenpasswords.txt)
```

**TIP:** Check content of both variables using `cat -vte`

```
echo "VALID_PASSWORD" | cat -vte
echo "PASSWORD" | cat -vte
```

Comment: +1 good advice. another method to view the contents of the variables: `od -c <<<"$VALID_PASSWORD"`

Comment: Yes agreed, `od -c` is even more detailed info.

Comment: When I add the echo "VALID_PASSWORD" | cat -vte
echo "PASSWORD" | cat -vte

Comment: When I add the echo "VALID_PASSWORD |cat -vte

Comment: Not getting your comments.